# Meteor apollo graphql query with react using props

Tags: reactjs, meteor, jsx, graphql, apollo

So far I managed to set up the schema and resolvers, apollo seems to be up and running. All that is left is to tie in my react component.

I am not totally sure the syntax or procedure to call the query

Say I have the following schema defined on the server:

```
  type Query {
    itemById(_id: String) : Item
  }

  schema {
    query: Query
  }

  type Item {
    _id: String!
    text: String!
  }
```

And the following component:

```
const Item = ({data}) => {
  return <div>{data.text}</div>;
}

Item.propTypes = {
  _id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

How do I decorate Item to get the item data, with the property "_id" taken from an external source such as session variable or url parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `_id` as a variable, like `avatarSize` in the docs:

http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html#graphql-options

(`Profile` is a component defined [at top](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html))